# login with facebook-php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is the error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Failed to connect to 255.255.255.255: Network is unreachable' in root__/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:150 Stack trace: #0

root__/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...', 'GET', Array) #1

root__/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(191): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2

root__/index.php(40): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect() #3 {main} thrown in

root__/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 150

and this is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

$appId='here is my app id';
$AppSecret='here is my app Secret';
$redirect='http://fos.a0001.net/';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $AppSecret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect);
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($session)){
        $request=new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me');
        $response=$request->execute();
        $graph=$response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
        $name=$graph->getName();
        echo $name;
}else{
        echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'">log in</a>';
}
```

i google it but i saw nothing like that

Comment: stucked at the same point. it is somehow related to "php" because it works fine with javascript and facebook-graph-api on the same server/website.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas it's a server error not php error maybe because i use free host and i don't have dedicated real ip for my site

Comment: when i tried it from my pc (for test only with dynamic ip) it worked

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem, it's from byethost privacy most likely so the only option is changing host like you did. Got stuck on this for two days lol